# How do I attach a circuit diagram to my question ?

Tags: support

I am unable to find a way other than attaching a link of the circuit diagram in question to my queries on stack exchange. Is there any way to attach an image file to the asked question?

Answer (score 2):

Hit ctrl-G on your keyboard, or click on the little icon that looks like a mountain range in the editor.

If you want to use the built-in schematic editor, hit ctrl-M instead.

Comment: I am afraid but my editor doesn't show any icon and also the crtl+G shortcut doesn't work..

Comment: In that case, you may need to wait until you have accumulated a higher reputation score on the site. In the meantime, leave the link in a comment and a reviewer or moderator will edit it into the question for you.

Comment: Okay. Thanks Dave.